# C++ Visual studio express 2010 unable to start program error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, runtime-error, visual-studio-express

I can compile code, but at run time I get some

impossible to start program F:/...algo.lib

I checked that launch program is ok, i rebuilded. i checked on google and did not find accurate reference to THIS problem. did you face it and did you fix it?

regards.

Comment: did you find the startup failure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you building a static library? You may want to check your Project settings for the output target type.

Comment: i am building a .lib. i watched output things in projet settings and could not find a target field. where is it exactly?

Comment: A .lib isn't a program. You can't run it by itself.

Comment: right-click the project in the solution explorer, select properties. its there on the right side. can't miss it (we'll, I couldn't anyway).

Comment: @PeteBecker then this is simple configuration question: have some code with a main.cpp with main class and some others, i want to start the program. should i run it as a .exe?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks. these settings are OK, and still unable to start.

Comment: If you're getting the same error (can't start a lib) and your project is setup to compile to an executable, then the only other two options I can think of are (a) you have a multi-project solution that builds both a .lib and a .exe and the .lib project is selected as your startup-project, or (b) for whatever reason a custom-start command has been has been configured for your project that some fiend has setup to launch a .lib. I sincerely doubt it is the latter. You have a solution file. How many projects are you building, and which one is "bold" (i.e. the startup)?